# Webpack dev server configuration refuse to work with full path to index

Tags: configuration, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

Hello I am trying to understand why does webpack dev server refuse to work with full path to my index.js. (I am using webpack with babel to build reactJS.)

At the moment my webpack.config is located in the same directory as my index.js file and due to that the declaration of the entry point of my index.js is just "./index". Here is how my webpack.config looks like:

```
module.exports = {
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
entry: [
   'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
   'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
   './index'
],
output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
   filename: 'bundle.js',
   publicPath: '/static/'
},
plugins: [
   new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
   new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
],
resolve: {
   extensions: ['', '.js']
},
module: {
   loaders: [{
     test: /\.js$/,
     loader: 'babel-loader',
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     include: __dirname
   }]
}};
```

With this configuration my project is build by babel and works just fine on the server!

My problem comes when I tried to specify a full path of my index.js entry point. I need that because I want to externalize the webpack and it's configuration from my FE code. To be sure that it will work I first tried not to rely that webpack.config and index.js are in the same directory but to specify the path of the index as full path name:

```
entry: [
   'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
   'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
   'D:/projects/myProject/index'
]
```

With this config babel seem to be able to navigate to the index.js and start compiling it, but it does encounter an unexpected (for me) error during the parse:

```
ERROR in D:/projects/myProject/index.js
Module parse failed: D:/projects/myProject/index.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import 'babel-core/polyfill';
| 
| import React from 'react';
 @ multi main
```

What do I miss, why webpack makes difference between relatively configured index.js and full path one?

(I made sure that the full path is correct)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit annoying investigation it appeared that my problem is specifying the Windows drives in uppercase. For some reason it appear that the index.js location full path should start with lowercase drive letter!

Hopefully this experience may be helpful to others.
Try using:

```
d:/Folder1/folder2/index.js
```

instead of

```
D:/Folder1/folder2/index.js
```